# In playstore can we have two apps with same name with different package - Android

Tags: android, google-play

I've upload application on google play store with my own package name.

Later client want to change the package name.

I've searched but i got that,  not able to change package name after publish.

what can i do for this?

and

In playstore can we have two apps with same name with different package?

Answer (score 19):

> In playstore can we have two apps with same name with different package?

Yes, you can have multiple apps in the play store with the same **display** name, but they have to have different package names (and the play store won't actually allow a second app with the same package name as another even to be uploaded)

> what can i do for this?

- You cannot change the package name.
- You can change the package name in your dev environment and upload it as a new app. All your ratings and download numbers will not transfer.

Comment: Lets assume I have 2 app, 1 for india country & other for US, Now is it possible to have same package name?

Comment: No, you can always name the packages to match your country, publish as two different apps, and limit distribution to that country. For example, `com.example.myapp.us` and `com.example.myapp.in`

Comment: @SaurabhKhare You can have same app with the same package name one for india and another for US. Then upload two apk but with different app names in the manifest.(Different app names, NOT package names)

Answer (score 1):

You can't. As stated [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/preparing.html#publishing-configure), seems that's one of the few things you cannot do.

> Choose a good package name
>
> Make sure you choose a package name that is suitable over the life of
>   your application. You cannot change the package name after you
>   distribute your application to users. You can set the package name in
>   application's manifest file. For more information, see the package
>   attribute documentation.

Comment: Adding to this answer, you can have the same app name, with different package names.