# Unable to upload app to android market with same appname and packagename for different countries

Tags: android

I am trying to upload app with same appname and packagename for different countries but getting the below error message.
For eg., trying to upload same app for two different countries;

For Sweden,
App Name: **AppName1**
Package Name: *com.sweden.app*

For US,
App Name: **AppName1**
Package Name: *com.us.app*

I have already uploaded AppName1 app for Sweden, but when trying to upload for US while entering Appname as AppName1, its is showing below error msg without uploading app.

"You have to choose another name for the app. This name has been used already on com.sweden.app"

Please anyone suggest something.

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21546047/in-playstore-can-we-have-two-apps-with-same-name-with-different-package-androi

Comment: @VedPrakash thanks but my problem scenario is different with mentioned in above link..

Answer (score 1):

You can not upload app which has a same app name and package name on the Google Server. You must need to choose another name for it, reason behind that is to avoid repetition of the app and to avoid confusion as a user perspective.

Comment: ok but uploading for different countries with same name.. is that not possible??

Comment: nop, I think its doesn't matter, server identifies the app with package name and app name. So I think its not possible @gIrL

Comment: @gIrL I think you are newbie to android development?

Comment: am not newbie but facing this issue for the first time.. while entering app name is shows the error message without uploading apk or anything..

Comment: @gIrL hmm its ok, no worries, but with same app name and package name you can't do it finally...

Comment: I have edited my question for clear and detailed understanding of problem.please check and suggest.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55968/discussion-between-girl-and-kishan-patel).

Answer (score 1):

Uploading two apps with same name and different/same package name can be done with different developer accounts only... It is not possible to upload two apps with same name from one developer account.