# Create new Android project by copying an existing project

Tags: android, eclipse

I am trying to create an android project by copying an existing project.  I am not hacking anyone's code :-)  I am trying a build a project which is going to be called as gold copy.  My juniors will download the gold copy and build their own application by change the necessary parameters like project name, package name, etc...  Each junior then can sign the APK and upload their project on their own in Google Play store.

Gold Copy project
I use Eclipse to create the gold copy project. Lets assume its just a Helloworld Android application Project and I created with the following details.

```
Application Name: GoldCopy
Project Name: GoldCopyPrj
Package Name: org.jeema.goldcopy
Activity Name: MainActivity
Layout Name: activity_main
```

I build the application and created a zip file.  Assume my first junior downloads the zip file and he wants to create his own application.  Assume he is using notepad++ to change the values and then open in eclipse.  What are the things he needs to change?

1. I think he definitely need to change the app_name in strings.xml.
2. Do he need to change the activity name or package name in the manifest file?
3. Anything else?

After he successfully creates the application he should be able to sign the APK and upload to Google Play.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change also the

```
    package="org.jeema"
```

to something else in order to be recognized as a new application.

You also need to create a new keystore for the Google Play.

Here is a small tutorial [enter link description here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-publish-to-the-android-market--mobile-2744)

Answer (score 1):

```
I think he definitely need to change the app_name in strings.xml.
```

No you do not, two apps can [have same name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21546047/in-playstore-can-we-have-two-apps-with-same-name-with-different-package-androi) as long as the package name is different.

> Do he need to change the activity name or package name in the manifest
>   file?

App store requires you to have unique package names (because they are used as identifiers for your app) therefore anyone who works off your app will need to change the package name if they want to publish it under their name.

Changing the activity name is not necessary.

[This](http://blog.javia.org/android-package-name/) gives more detail on why the package name needs to be unique.