# Can I click "unpublish" in Google Play, then create a new app with the same name as the old one?

Tags: android, google-play, apk, keystore, android-package-managers

Help! Lost the signature certificate, so we could not upload a new APK in Google Play. Could I click "Unpublish" in Google Play, create a new APK with a new signature certificate, then **upload it with the same name as the old one**?

What's important is the name, if the name can be the same, it is ideal.

Thanks all.

Comment: You can. But your current users will not get an update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can unpublish but once your application has been live on the market you cannot delete it.

Yes, you can have multiple apps in the play store with the same display name, but they have to have different package names

If you lost your keystore then there is no way that you can update the app in play sore( **it will cause a signature error** )!

The only way is that you can create an app with a new package name upload it to store and remove the old app.

Comment: inform me if you have confusion@Meggie

Comment: Thank you Amit. I just wonder if I should put a new name to the same APK?

Comment: I see what you mean, the display name in Google Play can be the same but the package name cannot be the same, right?

Comment: yes, you are right "package name cannot be the same". you can have multiple apps in the play store with the same display name.Yes, you can change the name whenever you want by changing android:label attribute of your application tag in AndroidManifest.xml file.

Comment: Tried already, I could not use the same title now, even the package name is changed...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21546047/in-playstore-can-we-have-two-apps-with-same-name-with-different-package-androi